# Error using ng-packagr : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I am unable to import the component defined in one of the sub module which I am packaging and referring in main project. Everything seems fine but I still see an error -

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve '@first-project/second-project/app/regist
>   ration/registration.component' in
>   'C:\Users\anujin\Documents\workspace-vs-code\ FirstProject\src\app'
>   ERROR in ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '@first-project/second-project/app/regist
>   ration/registration.component' in
>   'C:\Users\anujin\Documents\workspace-vs-code\ FirstProject\src\app'

I created two projects -

- FirstProject
- SecondProject

I created a `RegistrationComponent` in `SecondProject` which I need to use in `FirstProject`.

**FirstProject files :**

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@first-project/second-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tsickle": "^0.34.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

`ng-package.json` -

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "./src/public_api.ts"
    },
    "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
        "@angular/animations",
        "@angular/cdk",
        "@angular/common",
        "@angular/compiler",
        "@angular/forms",
        "@angular/core",
        "@angular/http",
        "@angular/material",
        "@angular/platform-browser",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
        "@angular/router",
        "core-js",
        "rxjs",
        "tsickle",
        "zone.js",
        "ng-packagr"
      ]
}
```

`public_api.ts`

```
export * from './app/app.module';
export * from './app/registration/registration.component';
```

I ran the following commands in `FirstProject` -

- npm run packagr
- cd dist
- npm pack

Then I referred the packaged `SecondProject` in `FirstProject`.

**FirstProject files -**

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "first-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@first-project/second-project": "<path>/SecondProject/dist/first-project-second-project-0.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from '@first-project/second-project/app/registration/registration.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.routing.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegistrationComponent } from '@first-project/second-project/app/registration/registration.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I did `npm install` in `FirstProject` and I see the reference under node modules created properly, but I do `npm start` here in `FirstProject`, it gives the following error -

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@first-project/second-project/app/regist
>       ration/registration.component' in 'C:\Users\anujin\Documents\workspace-vs-code\
>       FirstProject\src\app'
>       ERROR in ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@first-project/second-project/app/regist
>       ration/registration.component' in 'C:\Users\anujin\Documents\workspace-vs-code\
>       FirstProject\src\app'

I am unable to understand as what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared folder, create the RegistrationComponent in shared module and used it in both project. Please refer the following link, it will resolve your issue.

[Share code(component) between multiple projects](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11168)

[Code-Sharing-with-multiple-app-angular-project-using-base-components](https://www.henriksommerfeld.se/code-sharing-with-multi-app-angular-project-using-base-components/)

Comment: Your link gave me a direction to find out solution. Thanks a bunch. Up voting. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

please export your component in public.ts file

```
public_api.ts
export * from './app/RegistrationComponent.component';
export * from './app/app.module';
```

> FOR COMPONENTS: 
>   Using export makes the element visible. Adding it to
>   the entry file makes the class visible.

Read this : [The Angular Library Series - Creating a Library with Angular CLI](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5)

Comment: Same error. I have updated the `public_api.ts` as well. I did try this earlier but was still getting the same error. Tried again right now and see the same error.

Comment: @apun - you need to export your registration module also

Comment: But that's a component and not a module which I have already exported. Isn't it? There is only one app module which comes by default while generating project using `ng-cli`

Comment: @apun - you code is not clear , even in you question not able to locate which one is first projec t and which one second, if you can share code somehwere then i can able to help more

Comment: Sure, gimme a minute please. Sharing it.

Comment: You can access it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xX2M3uI29uw5IoLrEnNMO5yFw8D9TRhZ?usp=sharing). Please lemme know if you face any issues accessing it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @apun - this error you are getting it at time or compile time ?

Comment: Compile time when I am trying to build it. I am trying to create git hub repos for your reference.

Comment: I have added the repos here - [FirstProject](https://github.com/anujpin/FirstProject), [SecondProject](https://github.com/anujpin/SecondProject).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the package.json generated in the dist folder is missing the 'main' field, which expose the default .js file of the library.
To check this, you can just add it manually. In the node_modules of your application consuming the library, open the library bundle and add in the package.json something like:
`"main": "./esm2015/my-library-name-here.js"`. Of course, it depends on the name of your lib.
I've not found a clear way of defining that automatically with ng-packagr configuration, so I'm doing a home made script !